# Electron Updater Not Calling 'update-downloaded' event after downloading new app version

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

We are using following packages in our electron app

- electron-updater ^2.21.10
  "electron-builder": "^19.19.1",
  "electron": "^1.7.5

we have following code snippet where we calling autoUpdater.quitAndInstall(), but its not quitting current version of app and not installing new one.

```js
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', () => {
  app.focus(); // to let the update dialog have the focus when update is available
  dialog.showMessageBox({
    title: 'Test Application',
    type: 'none',
    message: 'Updates are downloaded, application will be quit for update...',
  }, () => {
    setImmediate(() => autoUpdater.quitAndInstall());
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, i'm the same problem.

Comment: @patricia I was missin on following statement   
app.on('ready', () => {
    autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()
})